# I need to remove all rows that are missing values in either of two columns in a data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a very very large data frame. It has 10 columns and millions of rows.

I have two columns that have a lot of empty fields. both columns are in *chr* format. I need to remove the rows with empty fields in either column.

I will try to provide an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
  start_loc = c("A St", "B St", ""),
  end_loc = c("D St", "", "F St"),
  id = c("m", "c", "m")
) %>% 
  {. ->> my_data}

my_data

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  start_loc end_loc id   
  <chr>     <chr>   <chr>
1 "A St"    "D St"  m    
2 "B St"    ""      c    
3 ""        "F St"  m
```

So, I need to remove all rows that have blank fields in `start_loc` and `end_loc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `nzchar` with `if_all` (assuming empty is `""` and not `NA`)

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>% 
   filter(if_all(c(start_loc, end_loc), nzchar))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  start_loc end_loc id   
  <chr>     <chr>   <chr>
1 A St      D St    m
```

---

Or use `if_any` and negate (`!`)

```
my_data %>%
    filter(!if_any(c(start_loc, end_loc), `==`, ""))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  start_loc end_loc id   
  <chr>     <chr>   <chr>
1 A St      D St    m
```

---

If there are both `""` and `NA`, we can use

```
my_data %>%
    filter(!if_any(c(start_loc, end_loc), ~ is.na(.)|. == ""))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  start_loc end_loc id   
  <chr>     <chr>   <chr>
1 A St      D St    m
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! I was really overcomplicating things.

Answer (score 0):

Using `rowSums` in base R -

```
my_data[rowSums(my_data[1:2] == '') == 0, ]

#  start_loc end_loc id   
#  <chr>     <chr>   <chr>
#1 A St      D St    m
```